# Can't instantiate class fields in JavaFX project

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

So I'm trying to move from Swing to JavaFX and I just declare the `start()` and `launch()` methods without knowing how they work. But below code prints false and false to the console. However when I click the button in the GUI, built with `Scene Builder`, that executes `myMethod()`, this time it prints true. Why does it say that `primaryStage` isn't instantiated?

*addition information:*
I also made this class my Controller, for the same reason - it needs access to the Stage reference. The full version of Main, which I didn't post, implements `Initializable` if that matters.

**As a bonus question** I was wondering if I need the field of `primaryStage` to reference the Application Stage, which there would only be one of?, in `myMethod()`.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        try {
            Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Sample.fxml")),600,400);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        primaryStage.show();
        //both lines below print false; As they should.
        System.out.println(this.primaryStage == null);
        myMethod();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void myMethod() {
        System.out.println(primaryStage == null);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

placing this FXML document in the same folder as above class will let you run Main to see that the button does indeed print true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Main">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#myMethod" text="Button" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Can you show how you create the listener relationship between the Button and MyMethod? And also please show the Controller.

Comment: And you say Main implements Initializable? Why did you remove it from this code?

Comment: @JamesWierzba I removed parts that seemed unnecesary for simplicity. the relationship is created in the FXML document `onAction="#myMethod"` and the method is also correctly executed. It's just the result that's surprising

Comment: It's quite possible the code you removed could be relevant to the issue. Also, a user may wish to recreate your problem to try to debug it, which is impossible if you don't show the code.

Comment: @JamesWierzba You now have both files that will let you run the program and confirm the behaviour. I hope it helps.

Comment: Don't use the `Application` subclass as the controller: it is not going to make anything simpler. The `launch()` method instantiates the `Application` subclass and calls the `start(...)` method. If you specify the same class in the `fx:controller` attribute, the `FXMLLoader` will create a *new instance* of the same class, and injects the `@FXML`-annotated fields into *that instance*. When you press the button, the handler method on the instance created by the `FXMLLoader` will be invoked, not on the instance created by the call to `launch()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `FXMLLoader` will create new instance of `application.Main` class, in where the `start()` method is not invoked and thus `private Stage primaryStage` is null.

It is better to separate the main class and the controller for the FXML, and pass the primary stage later if it is necessary:

```
...
try
{
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( getClass().getResource( "Sample.fxml" ) );
    Scene scene = new Scene( loader.load(), 600, 400 );

    ( (MyController) loader.getController() ).setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
    primaryStage.setScene( scene );
}
catch ( Exception e )
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
...
```

where the `MyController` class can be as simple as:

```
public class MyController {

    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }
}
```

but also can implement [Initializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) interface. Refer to [Introduction to FXML :: Controllers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Also note that you can get the scene and its stage from any node that is part of that constructed scene graph (i.e. a stage that is shown) by:

```
Scene scene = anynode.getScene();
Stage primaryStage = (Stage) anynode.getScene().getWindow();
```

Of course, for the secondary stages created by you the getWindow() will return that stage and not the primary stage.

Comment: That makes great sense. But how do I reference the Stage object in my separately defined controller, then?

Comment: I didn't know that controllers were defined as a `MyController` class? Do my controller class need to extend MyController to support a `getPrimaryStage()` function?

Comment: @user2651804 sorry for not being clear! MyController is _your_ class :),  that has an initialize() method (and of course additionally setter for primaryStage in our case). Something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).

Comment: Why are you even trying to create a reference to it in the controller at all? Just call `getScene().getWindow()` on any node when you need access to it.

Comment: @user2651804 see update. The link I provided in the above comment is for JavaFX 2.2. In the asnwer there is for the JavaFX 8.

Comment: @James_D that is why I mentioned "if it is necessary" in the answer. But will add your note to the answer.

Comment: @James_D Ok, I see. When you say that it is never necessary, you don't mean to imply that it's never useful though, right? In my case, while I was actually looking for your kind of solution, it turned out that wasn't so straightforward since I don't have an identifier for my Node, the button. Only it's function body.

Comment: I do mean to imply that it's never useful. You'll almost always inject *something* into the controller. In the rare cases you don't, and if you really don't want to inject something specifically for that purpose, you can always make the handler method accept an `Event` parameter. Then you can call `getSource` on the event and downcast it to a `Node`, then call `getScene().getWindow()`. I prefer in these cases just to inject the root element of the FXML into the controller and use that, though - it avoids downcasts.

Comment: @James_D ultimately I will still have to downcast from Window to Stage, I'm not missing anything here, right?

Comment: @user2651804 it depends want you want to do with Stage/Window further. To minimize by using setIconified() needs downcasting etc.

Comment: Maybe, so I should say it avoids *some* downcasts. (Maybe all of them, depending on what you need the window for.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need at all to jump through any of these hoops to get access to the window. You can just call `getScene().getWindow()` on any node to get the window in which it is displayed (and of course you can just inject any node into your controller in the usual way).

Don't use the `Application` subclass as the controller class: you will have (at least) two different instances (one created by the `launch()` method, because it's the `Application` subclass, and one created by the `FXMLLoader`, because it's the controller class). Different fields will be initialized in the different instances.

Create a controller class, and inject at least one node into it:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private Parent root ;

    @FXML
    private void myMethod() {
        Window window = root.getScene().getStage();
        // assuming you are running as a standalone application, the window 
        // will actually be a Stage instance.

        window.hide();  // for example...
    }
}
```

Use this as your controller class and inject the node into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<HBox xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller" fx:id="root">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#myMethod" text="Button" />
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: Would you say it is better practice to have a reference to the root Node rather than the Stage itself? From my perspective it appears like there's no difference.

Comment: Yes, but only because it avoids all the ugly wiring to the controller class. Note here I don't need to get the controller from the loader and call methods on it, etc. Anytime I need to get the controller from the loader, I regard it as a sign that something is wrong in my design (though there are certainly cases where it is easier than the alternative). The application code should just load the UI component and do something with it: it shouldn't need to worry about how the UI component is controlled. And again, the number of times you don't already have *something* injected is tiny.

Comment: @user2651804, there can be scenarios where there is a primary stage, but this controller's fxml is not part of it. Namely 2 different stages where the we need the stage not returned with getWindow(). But it would be "code smell" as well.

Comment: @user2651804, eventually you will have multiple controllers when the app gets complex. And there will be requirement to transfer data within these conrtollers. There are different approaches that already posted for the similar questions on SO here. In those cases you may want to get the controller from the FXMLloader, or even use fxmlloadler.setController() option for some places.

Comment: @UlukBiy I've come to the conclusion that as soon as you reach that point, a D.I. Framework is worth having in order to keep the design elegant. Use [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/), which is a FX-oriented D.I. framework, or use a standard one: [here's](https://github.com/james-d/SpringFXExample) my Spring example. But kind of off-topic for this question :).

Comment: Yeah, it may have went a bit out of scope now. Thanks a lot guys, both of you! :)
I have always had very much trouble understand the concept of MVC-pattern. could you maybe just really fast reply what you meant with application code? Is it my controller?
And does talking about a `model` make sense without a database? yes/no will suffice, thanks guys!!

Comment: By application code I meant (this may or may not be the standard usage in this context) the code that assembles the application, i.e. loads the fxml and puts it in a scene, perhaps initializes a model, etc. So in this example the code in the `Application` subclass. A model does make sense without a database (it represents the data in the application, regardless of where that data came from). My Spring/FX example referenced in a previous comment is kind of my ideal for organizing an application (real life applications may not meet this ideal...).